# Why the buffer isn't overflowing with this code?

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow

This is the C code that I am compiling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
long val=0x41414141;
char buf[20];

printf("Correct val's value from 0x41414141 -> 0xdeadbeef!\n");
printf("Here is your chance: ");
scanf("%24s",&buf);

printf("buf: %s\n",buf);
printf("val: 0x%08x\n",val);

if(val==0xdeadbeef)
system("/bin/sh");
else {
printf("WAY OFF!!!!\n");
exit(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Here, I am expecting an overflow in `long val` if user inputs string 24 character long, changing the value in `val`. But it just doesn't get overflowed even if string is long enough. Can someone please explain this behaviour?

I am on macOS. This is what `gcc -v` spits out:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Also, after googling a bit I tried gcc with these flags:

```
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -o overflow_example overflow_example.c
```

still, the result is same.

This code is part of `narnia` wargame challenge on [overthewire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/narnia/). I managed to crack this challenge on their remote shell, where it was behaving as expected. Now, I am trying to reproduce this same challenge on my local system and facing this issue. Please help.

EDIT: For all the people yelling out about UB: like I said, this was one of the challenge to be solved on [overthewire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/narnia/), so it cannot have UB. There are some blogs ([here's on I found](https://infamoussyn.com/2013/11/18/overthewire-narnia-level-0-4-writeup/)) that provide walkthrough for this challenge with reasonable logical explanation for *why* the code behaves the way it does, with which I agree. I also understand that the compiled binary is platform dependent. *So, what am I to do to produce this binary with potential overflow on my local system?*

Comment: Undefined behavior = behavior that is not defined. There is no guarantee where those variables are allocated in memory.

Comment: @Lundin Sir, please emphasise that these two are not related points.

Comment: You're exploiting *undefined behavior*, and undefined behavior is by its very definition undefined. Also, the stack layout created by a compiler depends very much on the compiler, and a hack like this may not work on all compilers. Especially if there's some optimizations going on (which might optimize out the `val` variable completely).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is NOT undefined behaviour. This code is expected to cause an overflow. Like I mentioned, this is a challenge from overthewire.org. I managed to solve it on their remote shell. I understood the memory layout, predicted the input, handcrafted the input, and sure enough, the var got overwritten(with 0xdeadbeef) spawning me the shell! My question is: Why am I not able to reproduce this very same problem on my local system? What is it that I am missing? What optimisations (if any) should I remove form my compiler?

Comment: Writing out of bounds leads to undefined behavior. That you know (or *think* that you know) what will happen doesn't make it less UB in the term of the C specification. That it apparently doesn't work as you expected it to is a clear evidence of UB.

Comment: @JayBhavsar If multiple people tell you it is undefined behaviour, there might be some truth to the statement. And just to make sure yes this is undefined behaviour. I am suprised that this even worked once.

Comment: @JayBhavsar google "C undefined behaviour". Yes, the code causes a buffer overflow, but the consequences of the buffer overflow cannot be generally predicted, because it is "undefined behaviour".

Comment: _Why am I not able to reproduce this very same problem on my local system?_ : because it is not exactly the same platform (same OS, same compiler version, same compiler flags used etc.)

Comment: Apparantly the variables get laid out differently on the stack on your mac. Printing the address of `val` and `buf` should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly the variables get laid out differently on the stack on your mac.

Wrapping them in a struct will ensure that they are placed in the order you want.

Since there is the possibility of padding, let's turn it off. For `gcc`, the precompiler directe `#pragma pack` controls struct packing.

```
int main(){
#pragma pack(1)
  struct {
    char buf[20];
    long val=0x41414141;
  } s;
#pragma pack()
  printf("Correct val's value from 0x41414141 -> 0xdeadbeef!\n");
  printf("Here is your chance: ");
  scanf("%24s",&s.buf);

  printf("buf: %s\n",s.buf);
  printf("val: 0x%08x\n",s.val);

  if(s.val==0xdeadbeef)
    system("/bin/sh");
  else {
    printf("WAY OFF!!!!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, wrapping them ensures their place. I did so, and printed their addresses (`printf("%p\n",(void*)&a);`) in both cases, with wrapping and without wrapping. The difference between those 2 addresses is 24 bytes, which is expected. Even so, entering 24 char long string does not overwrite `val`.

Comment: I would expect the difference between the adresses to be 20 bytes, not 24. Sometimes the compiler inserts extra bytes between variables when you use the debug flag, so try skipping the `-g` from the compile command.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the difference should be 20 bytes. Even with `-g` flag removed, it's still 24 bytes. Instead of scanning 24 char, if I scan 28 chars and input 28 char long string, the last 4 bytes do overwrite `val` (This makes sense). Now I understand why the binary behaves the way id does. This was helpful. Now if you can explain this, you'll make my day: Why did my compiler inserted extra 4 bytes between those two variables?

Comment: I probably tries to always place `long` variables on an address that is a multiple of 8. Look for `#pragma pack` in the compiler manual and surround the struct declaration with suitable values. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

It's **undefined behavior** because C functions do not check whether an argument is too big for its buffer or not.

Comment: This is NOT undefined behaviour. This code is expected to cause an overflow. Like I mentioned, this is a challenge from overthewire.org. I managed to solve it on their remote shell. I understood the memory layout, predicted the input, handcrafted the input, and sure enough, the var got overwritten(with 0xdeadbeef) spawning me the shell! My question is: Why am I not able to reproduce this very same problem on my local system? What is it that I am missing? What optimisations (if any) should I remove form my compiler? Also, for scanf function, it will read 24 characters, no more, no less.

Comment: @JayBhavsar: actually it *is* undefined behaviour - the fact that you made this exploit work in one scenario proves nothing - you are making a lot of assumptions about how undefined behaviour will play out, which happened to work for you in one case, but which can not be relied upon in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean.

1) Are you concerned that your input string will create a number that will be too big to store in a long. This will not happen the number will simply wrap round.
2) Are you concerned that you'll read to memory beyond the bounds of buf? In C this will produce undefined behavior not necessarily a crash.

buf is on the stack (could be just as well on the heap) so you can just keep writing to memory from the address where buf starts. The compiler will generate code that will not do a bounds check for you. So if you go beyond the 20byte you'll eventually start overwriting other parts of memory that do not belong block of memory you've set aside for buf.